# C# Linq2XML get parent attribute from child element value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, selectnodes

I close my last question as it was commented that not enough research had been done. The more I research them more confused I am getting. What I think should work in my understanding and from post here and elsewhere is not working.

```
XML sample
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
        <schmeata>
            <classschema name="Space">                  
                <base_class>Space</base_class>
            </classschema>
            <classschema name="Tapestry">       
                <base_class>File</base_class>
            </classschema>
            <classschema name="Document">       
                <base_class>File</base_class>
            </classschema>
        </schmeata>
        </multistatus>
```

I am trying to get the name attribute of the classschema nodes that have base_class children with the 'File' value. so the result should be 'Tapestry' and 'Document'

I can easily return all classschemata nodes with

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema", nsmgr))               
            {
                    strNode = node.Attributes["name"].Value;                       
                    responseString += strNode +" ";                   
            }
            return responseString;
```

And I can get the base_class value = to 'File' by looping through all the base_class nodes like this.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema/DAV:base_class", nsmgr))              
            {                    
                if (node.InnerText == "File")
                {                     
                    strNode = node.InnerText;
                    responseString += strNode +" ";
                }                  
            }
            return responseString;
```

but if I try and filter or use axis to reference the parent node from the child I am failing.

An example of my filtering efforts are based at the SelectNodes method.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[/DAV:base_class(contains,'File')]", nsmgr))  or
```

foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[/DAV:base_class=='File']", nsmgr))

along with many, many other variations as examples I have seen is hard to tell if it is LINQ2XML or XDocument and mix in for PHP or other languages where aren't always specified I am now jumpled.

My next attempt will be SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschemata[/DAV:baseclass(contains,'File')]"@name,nsmgr);
and variations on that.

I have thought from other examples that they had exactly what I wanted but when implemented did not work, for reasons I cannot explain.

Comment: If this is working: `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema"` then just check if the child node has `File` and only then add it to the result string.

Comment: `....[contains(DAV:base_class,'File')]` or `....[DAV:base_class='File']`

Comment: I have stated I already tried that in the SelectNodes and I expected it to work but it doesn't 'foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[/DAV:base_class(contains,'File')]", nsmgr))' 
I believe the namespace still needs to be qualified with the / to indicate child of classschemata or are you saying it should be checked within the loop?

Comment: WOW, now it is working.'foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[DAV:base_class='File']", nsmgr))
 strNode = node.Attributes["name"].Value;'
Is returning exactly what I want. I would have tried with both single and double = but now it is returning what is expected. Thank you for having me double check my previous attempts.

Comment: @har07 your answer did guide me to the solution. Thank you. I cannot vote on the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result you are after. Basically it looks for all `classschema` elements that have a first element with `Value == "File"` and then selects their `name` attributes `Value`. Please note I also used the `string.Join` method (pretty handy for stuff like this) to turn the result into a space delimited string which is what you need.

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("YourFile.xml");

var result = xmlDoc.Descendants("{DAV:}classschema")
    .Where(x => x.Elements().First().Value == "File")
    .Attributes("name")
    .Select(x => x.Value);

string spaceDelimited = string.Join(" ", result);
```

Comment: The example I used for the xml is completely stripped down to the bare minimum for explanation. The File element will be one of about 30-40 elements and not necessarily the first one.
I am resinstalling VS as it says my free community edition has completed its 30 day trial.

Comment: So would ' .Where(x => x.Elements().Value == "File")' also be valid to return the classschema if any child element node contained the File as a value?

Comment: @hammertime yes it will. You could have just tried it yourself by giving it a bigger file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using that now works. I would swear on a stack of Bibles I had done this in earlier testing and it filed. But it does work. In posting the code I see that the inner loop I was using is now commented out and was the problem. I was looping something that did not need to be looped so was returning empty.

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[DAV:base_class='File']", nsmgr))

            {
                //strNode = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                //if (node.InnerText == "File")
               // {
                    strNode = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                    //strNode = node.InnerText;
                    responseString += strNode +" ";
               // }                   
            }
            return responseString;
```

Thanks you for the help.
My next step will be to use each of the returned nodes and get all base_class elements and filter for only some of them to be returned. Not sure what I am looking for yet. Need to evaluate the XML to look for uniquenesss to capture what I want further.
Meaning now that I have the only classschema nodes with children elements containing 'File' get some of the child element siblings but not all. Challenge for another day.